# Using two-legged OAuth2 with Youtube Analytics API

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to connect to the [Youtube analytics api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/) using the [node.js client library for Google apis](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). I managed to get access to my [Google analytics data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) using JWT and a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) but unfortunately the YouTube analytics API doesn't support service accounts.

Is there a way to simulate the server to server method of authenticating (without user interaction)?

P.S. I will be accessing my own data.

Comment: You should be able to authenticate your code once.  Save your Refresh token and then use that in all future requests.